# Is a static HTML element not affected by positioned elements?

Tags: html, css, css-position

Imagine we have a blog, with the title and date sitting above some text:

```
<div class="blogHead">
  <h1>My blog title</h1>
  <p class="blogDate">The date</p>
</div>

<p class="blogText">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
```

We also want the date to sit to the far right of the title. One way is to to position it's parent (.blogHead) as relative, and then use absolute positioning on the date:

```
.blogHead {
    position: relative;
}

.blogDate {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}
```

This works. But, if I also make the position property of the h1 element absolute then the text moves to the top of the browser and clashes with the .blogHead div.

```
h1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

What is it about the h1's position that effects the relationship between it's parent and the subsequent non-positioned p element?

---

PS: can anyone suggest a better title? It seems difficult to search this problem out.

Comment: I think the answer is within the documentation or the definition of positon:absolute https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: I was looking here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Comment: well, it's simple both elements are absolute so removed from the flow thus their container is having a height equal to 0 that's why the bottom text is pulled up ... the main key is *removed from the flow*, if you got it you will understand

Comment: What about the relative positioning of the div? Is that out of the flow as well?

Comment: no it's not ...

Comment: This is a pretty good article on positioning: https://cssreference.io/positioning/

Comment: Thanks @Jon P. That is a much better source. It mentions flow and ties in top, bottom and z-index in a more comprehensive way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely positioned elements are positioned in relation to the nearest ancestor with `position:relative`, if there is no such ancestor then the body is used.

Your actual problem is coming about because the `blogHead` div collapses as the absolutely positioned content is removed from the normal flow.

We can see this if we add a border to `blogHead`.

```css
.blogHead {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.blogDate {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}

h1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="blogHead">
  <h1>My blog title</h1>
  <p class="blogDate">The date</p>
</div>

<p class="blogText">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
```

You have a couple of options here [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) is a modern approach. Alternatively you could look at floats, display:inline-block, or manually giving `.blogHead` hieght.

I'll provide you with a flexbox solution.

```css
.blogHead {
  /*Set the container to flex box*/
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 12px;
}

.blogHead>* {
  /*Set flex elements to fill the space equally*/
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.blogDate {
  text-align: right;
}

h1 {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="blogHead">
  <h1>My blog title</h1>
  <p class="blogDate">3 Oct 2018</p>
</div>

<p class="blogText">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
```

Here are some quick and dirty examples of the other approaches I mentioned:

- [Add height to the container](http://jsfiddle.net/zLerx5qw/)
- [Float the date](http://jsfiddle.net/w46ynht7/)
- [Use `inline-block` for both](http://jsfiddle.net/2xL6gqt8/)

Answer (score 0):

Position absolute is absolute to the browser window, so 0,0 is the top left corner of the browser. Put them both in a container div and make the position absolute on the container.

Once you make something position absolute it is no longer in the flow of the document and doesn't affect the flow of other elements therefore no longer pushing the other elements down.

Comment: I was thinking that the the header h1 and p were absolute to the div, not the window. And then the div, being only relative, should push the text down???

Comment: Once you make the two elements absolute the container div is empty as far as document flow goes making it no longer affect the flow of other elements.

Comment: This is technically incorrect. Elements with `position:absolute` are positioned using the closest ancestor with `position:relative`. If there is no ancestor with `position:relative` then, the browser window is used. See: http://jsfiddle.net/5scr0vox/